# threadsafe wrapper on std::unordered_map

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, unordered-map

I am trying to implement a thread safe wrapper class on top of std::unordered_map
is it safe to have begin and end functions as below?

```
        std::unordered_map<Key, T, Hash, Pred, Alloc> umap;
        iterator begin() {
            return umap.begin();
        }   
        iterator end() {
            return umap.end();
        }
```

Also please comment if there is any obvious mistakes in copy/move operator= implementation

```
    concurrent_unordered_map& operator=(const concurrent_unordered_map& other) ;
    {
        if (this!=&other) {
          std::lock(entry_mutex, other.entry_mutex);
          std::lock_guard<boost::shared_mutex> _mylock(entry_mutex, std::adopt_lock);
          std::shared_lock<boost::shared_mutex> _otherlock(other.entry_mutex, std::adopt_lock);
          umap = other.umap;
        }
        return *this;           
    }
    concurrent_unordered_map& operator=(concurrent_unordered_map&& other) 
    {
        if (this!=&other) {
          std::lock(entry_mutex, other.entry_mutex);
          std::lock_guard<boost::shared_mutex> _mylock(entry_mutex, std::adopt_lock);
          std::shared_lock<boost::shared_mutex> _otherlock(other.entry_mutex, std::adopt_lock);
          umap = std::move(other.umap)
        }
        return *this;       
    }
```

Thanks
MJV

Comment: `begin` and `end` functions are already provided for you in the standard library. And no, they aren't thread safe.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs to codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: As iterator may be invalidated by other thread, you can't provide begin/end. You should instead provide a `for_each` method.

Comment: Instead of reinventing the wheel consider using TBB's [concurrent hash map](https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/reference/containers_overview/concurrent_hash_map_cls.htm) instead.

Comment: @sjdowling: or [concurrent unordered map](https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/reference/containers_overview/concurrent_unordered_map_cls.htm), which API is closer to the one of C++ unordered map.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot create a thread-safe container that offers the same interface as the underlying standard container, even if you synchronize every method call. That is because the interface specification itself is not intended to be used in a multi-threading environment.

Here's an example: Let's say you have multiple threads that are concurrently inserting to the same container object:

```
c->insert(new_value);
```

Because you synchronized every method call this works just fine, no problem here.

But at the same time, another thread tries to loop through all elements in the container:

```
auto itr = c->begin();
while (itr != c->end())
{
    // do something with itr
    ++itr;
}
```

I wrote it this way to make the problem clear: Even if the calls to begin and end are internally synchronized, you cannot perform the operation "loop through all elements" atomically, because you need more than one method call to complete this task. This scenario breaks as soon as any other thread inserts something to the container while the loop is running.

So if you want to have a container that can be used without external synchronization, you need a thread-safe interface. For example, the "loop through all elements" task can be done atomically by supplying a for_each method:

```
c.for_each([](const value_type& value)
{
    // do something with value
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot simply synchronize each method and get a thread safe object, because some operations require more than one method call, and break if the container is mutated between the method calls.

A classic example of this is iteration.

An easy way to thread safe anything is to abuse C++14 features like this:

```
template<class T>
struct synchronized {
  // one could argue that rvalue ref qualified version should not be
  // synchronized...  but I think that is wrong
  template<class F>
  std::result_of_t< F(T const&) > read( F&& f ) const {
    auto&& lock = read_lock();
    return std::forward<F>(f)(t);
  }
  template<class F>
  std::result_of_t< F(T&) > write( F&& f ) {
    auto&& lock = write_lock();
    return std::forward<F>(f)(t);
  }
  // common operations, useful rvalue/lvalue overloads:
  // get a copy of the internal guts:
  T copy() const& { return read([&](auto&&t)->T{return t;}); }
  T copy() && { return move(); }
  T move() { return std::move(*this).write([&](auto&&t)->T{return std::move(t);}); }
private:
  mutable std::shared_timed_mutex mutex;
  std::shared_lock<std::shared_timed_mutex> read_lock() const {
    return std::shared_lock<std::shared_timed_mutex>(mutex);
  }
  std::unique_lock<std::shared_timed_mutex> write_lock() {
    return std::unique_lock<std::shared_timed_mutex>(mutex);
  }
  T t;
public:
  // relatively uninteresting boilerplate
  // ctor:
  template<class...Args>
  explicit synchronized( Args&&... args ):
    t(std::forward<Args>(args)...)
  {}
  // copy ctors: (forwarding constructor above means need all 4 overloads)
  synchronized( synchronized const& o ) :t(std::forward<decltype(o)>(o).copy()) {}
  synchronized( synchronized const&& o ):t(std::forward<decltype(o)>(o).copy()) {}
  synchronized( synchronized & o )      :t(std::forward<decltype(o)>(o).copy()) {}
  synchronized( synchronized && o )     :t(std::forward<decltype(o)>(o).copy()) {}
  // copy-from-T ctors: (forwarding constructor above means need all 4 overloads)
  synchronized( T const& o ) :t(std::forward<decltype(o)>(o)) {}
  synchronized( T const&& o ):t(std::forward<decltype(o)>(o)) {}
  synchronized( T & o )      :t(std::forward<decltype(o)>(o)) {}
  synchronized( T && o )     :t(std::forward<decltype(o)>(o)) {}
};
```

which seems obscure, but works pretty well:

```
int main() {
  synchronized< std::unordered_map<int, int> > m;
  m.write( [&](auto&&m) {
    m[1] = 2;
    m[42] = 13;
  });
  m.read( [&](auto&&m) {
    for( auto&& x:m ) {
      std::cout << x.first << "->" << x.second << "\n";
    }
  });
  bool empty = m.read( [&](auto&&m) {
    return m.empty();
  });
  std::cout << empty << "\n";
  auto copy = m.copy();
  std::cout << copy.empty() << "\n";

  synchronized< std::unordered_map<int, int> > m2 = m;
  m2.read( [&](auto&&m) {
    for( auto&& x:m ) {
      std::cout << x.first << "->" << x.second << "\n";
    }
  });
}
```

the idea is you stick your operations into lambdas, which execute within a synchronized context.

The coding style is a bit obscure, but not unmanageable (at least with C++14 features).

A nice feature of C++11 is that two `const` operations on the same container are legal, even if from two different threads.  So the `read` is simply passed a `const` reference to the container, and almost anything you can do inside it is legal to do in parallel with another thread.

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2a72cd69c70f6d24)

Comment: `read` should return `std::result_of_t< F(T const&) >` and `write` `std::result_of_t< F(T&) >` respectively. `-> decltype(std::forward<F>(f)(t))` for both cases may be more readable, or even `auto` since I don't think SFINAE would be terribly useful.

Comment: @Casey fixed, as well as some other errors.  I like `auto`, but I don't want porting to pre-C++14 to be to annoying.  Note that `result_of_t` doesn't support SFINAE any more than `auto` does.  Communicating that the result of calling the function on the stored type is the result of calling `write` or `read` seems worthwhile.

Comment: this code does not compile,  i think the are not correct the {, ) for the definition of the copy operations...

Comment: @carlos.baez yes, was missing a `);` and a `;`.  Added a `.move()` and test code for copies.  Updated live example.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible (but not generally useful) to have a thread-safe `std::unordered_map` implementation - problem is that each iterator object would need to lock a recursive mutex until its destructor ran.  Not only would that be a bit slow, and iterators then swollen in memory usage, there are functional issues: it's not unusual to keep iterators around even when they're not "currently" being used to read or write the container (e.g. for some secondary index, or as "cursors", or because after using them their destruction is lazily left until the enclosing scope exits or owning object is destroyed): that means other threads may be blocked for a very, very long time, and in practice the program logic around the container operations might constitute a kind of dead-lock.